# How to split a string into doubles and add them to array C#

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string, split

I have a string like

```
"1.898, -1.456, 233.556, 34546.8"
```

How would I make an array of doubles in C#
Do I have to use regex or split function?

I was trying something like:

```
string[] aux = ORIGINALtext.Split(',');
foreach (string val in aux)
{
   double value = double.Parse(val);
   Console.WriteLine(value);

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
double[] doubles = Array.ConvertAll(myDoubles.Split(','), double.Parse);
```

Or using LINQ

```
double[] doubles = myDoubles.Split(',').Select(double.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: Never seen .Select(double.Parse) before but i like it! Nice idea

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] str = "1.898, -1.456, 233.556, 34546.8".Split(',');
double[] doubles = new double[str.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    doubles[i] = double.Parse(str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few different ways:

```
ORIGINALtext.Split(',').Select(s =>
        float.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

ORIGINALtext.Split(',').Select(s =>
        Convert.ToDouble(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

foreach (string s in ORIGINALtext.Split(',')) {
    double x;
    if (double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Number,
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out x)) {
        yield return x;
    }
}
```

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` will make the compiler use a consistent format across all country lines. (Dot for decimal separator, Comma for thousand separator, etc.)

With `NumberStyles`, you can control which number styles you want to allow (surrounding white space, signed numbers, thousand separator, etc.). You can also pass it to `float.Parse`, but not to `Convert.ToDouble`.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string using the comma delimiter and then use Double.Parse() to parse the individual string elements into doubles.

```
var s = "1.898, -1.456, 233.556, 34546.8";
var split = s.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var doubles = new double[s.Length];
for(var i=0; i < split.Length; i++) {
    doubles[i] = Double.Parse(split[i].Trim());
}
```

Comment: double.Parse doesn't care about spaces.